# How to allow request outgoing from docker container only to specifiic urls?

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx, docker-compose

### What we have

---

1. **images:nginx** - docker container for proxy implemented with nginx:

```docker
FROM nginx:1.21-alpine
```

built with

`docker build -f ./docker/dev/nginx/Dockerfile -t "dev/images:nginx" .`

The nginx configuration for it is:

```nginx
http {
    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default upgrade;
        '' close;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name editor.localhost;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://nodejs:3000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }
    }

}
```

---

2. **images:nodejs** - docker container with the main server on node.js:

```docker
FROM node:16.10-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

CMD npm run dev
```

built with

`docker build -f ./docker/dev/nodejs/Dockerfile -t "dev/images:nodejs" .`

---

**Finally**, I run it with

`docker-compose -f "dev.yml" --compatibility --project-name "dev_project_name" up -d --remove-orphans`

The contents of `dev.yml` are as follows:

```yml
version: "2.1"
services:
  nginx: 
    image: dev/images:nginx
    volumes:
      - ./docker/dev/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    depends_on:
      - nodejs
    networks:
      internal:
      external:

  nodejs:
    image: dev/images:nodejs
    restart: "no"
    environment:
      JWT_SECRET: ${JWT_SECRET}
      NEXTAUTH_URL: ${BASE_URL}
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: "${PATH_TO_NEXTJS_APP}"
        target: /usr/src/app
        read_only: false
    networks:
      internal:

networks:
  external:
    driver: bridge
    internal: false

  internal:
    driver: bridge
    internal: true
```

### Current situation

Everything works fine, but...
We need our nodejs server to make request to some specific remote host (by url) outside of docker host (where all our containers are running). According to configuration above nodejs server does not have at all a direct access outside of docker host, because it's not connected to external network, but nginx does.

### What we need

a) So, is there a way to allow outside requests from the nodejs server go through the nginx proxy without including the container of the nodejs server to external network?

or

b) If there is no such a way, then if we include the nodejs container to external network, then how to limit an interaction of the container of the nodejs server only to outgoing requests to a particular remote URL?

Comment: would that request be https?

Comment: @jabbson, rather yes